# Considerations between OpenWebConfiguration and ConfigurationManager for a MVC5 App

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a setting I need to read from Web.config for my ASP.NET MVC5 application.

```
<configuration>
    <appSettings>
        <add key="MyKey" value="MyValue" />
    </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

I saw an example where someone recommended utilizing OpenWebConfiguration, but I normally use ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MyKey"]. Checking the MSDN documentation, the OpenWebConfiguration looks older, but still valid. I plan to deploy my application to an IIS server. Did ConfigurationManager replace OpenWebConfiguration, or are they meant for different tasks?

Thank you,
Dan Chase

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`OpenWebConfiguration` is something specifique to the `web.config` file.

`ConfigurationManager` is hybrid to configurations files, so it can read information from `app.config`, `web.config` and `mobile.config` files.

Another consideration is that the `OpenWebConfiguration` allows you to change the web configuration file easily. `OpenWebConfiguration` is available on the `System.Web` while the `ConfigurationManager` is on the `System.Configuration`.

Use the `ConfigurationManager` because it is hybrid and if you don't need to change the configuration file, just read the defined configurations. I always use `ConfigurationManager` in web, forms, services, etc to read appSettings and ConnectionStrings.